# What is the height from where the two lines intersect?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I apologize in advance for my English, but I really want to learn.

I took two lines and intersected them. |BD| and |AC| parallel but no length information

Question: Is it possible to find the length of |EF|? and how? they seem to be related but at the same time the information is missing

[BD] // [AG] Parallel

|BD| & |AG| : No length information

|BG| & |AG| & |DH| & |CH| : have length information

Question: |BG| & |AG| & |DH| & |CH| ------> |EF| related? is there an equation?

i know: |BD| and |GC| information, gives us an equation by similarity.

[image: geogebra example]

Comment: I figured it out with a little digging. |EF|=(|BG|*(|AG|-|CH|+|BD|))/(|AG|-|CH|) and |BD| with |EF| are somehow related, so we cannot think independently.

Comment: and |BD|=|GC|+|CH| It was understandable visually, but I didn't understand it.

Comment: You would have to define a lot of stuff for someone to be able to answer this question. What are the 2 intersecting lines, what are the points A to H?

Comment: @FadeelKhan Presumably $BG$, $DH$, and $EF$ are perpendicular to $AC$.

Comment: I edited the image, it should be visible now. It was such a funny question, until I didn't spend some time playing around with it for some reason, I instinctively thought I could just relate the slope information to the height, but now it seems silly. Moreover |BD|=|AH|-|AG| but I already said that we know the information of perpendicular lines. I just thought if we didn't know the information between the two points, we could relate it. Now I understand better through the equation that it is not.

Comment: Yes, ( [BG] // [DH] // [EF] ⊥ [AF] ) and [AF] // [BD]